Tips to Model/Simulate US Propagation/Energy Distribution From a Curved Surface Through Three Mediums?
I am working on a problem involving a cylindrical US transducer designed for radial emission. Positioned vertically (axial length perpendicular to the ground), the transducer emits energy circumferentially in 360° from all points along its curved, axial shell (Surface Area: 37.699 mm2). Power is supplied continuously for 10 seconds to the transducer and distributed uniformly across this curved emitting surface. ~50% of the electrical energy input is converted into heat, and the remaining ~50% is converted into mechanical/ultrasound energy.
The transducer dimensions are as follows: Axial length/height = 6 mm, radial length (non-emitting diameter) = 2 mm, Radius of curvature = 1 mm. The transducer operates within a biological lumen (37°C), held coaxial with the lumen by an inflated cooling balloon. The balloon circulates cooled normal (0.9%) saline of known volume and flow rate. Wave propagation from any point on the transducer’s emitting surface travels radially through: (Medium 1: 4.2 mm of cooled, circulated saline), (Medium 2: 1.3 mm), and thereafter through (Medium 3). The material properties for all media (e.g., acoustic impedance, density, speed of sound, etc.) are well-defined.
I am seeking advice on physics-based approaches, simulation tools, or accessible models capable of accommodating radial ultrasound distribution from a curved surface, fluid circulation’s impact on wave propagation in Medium 1, and propagation through three homogenous, but distinct, media. Importantly, I aim to avoid reliance on advanced coding or scripting. A practical, cost-effective solution suitable for academic or small business use is especially valuable. Any guidance – whether through simulation platforms, existing models, or expert recommendations?

Congratulations on cleansing that irrelevant clutter of one sentence thanking people for their time and stripping away matlab as a tag despite the fact that recommendations, if any are received, will almost undoubtedly use matlab toolboxes like k-wave. Forums are all the same, less concerned with answering questions than they are policing them.
